# Regex match everything in a list from start character

Tags: php, regex, list, multiline

I just can't manage to make this work. I'm trying to make a php regex to match the following set:

*Random start text that shouldn't be matched*

*List title:*
**list item

List item

list-item

List Item

List ITEM**

*rest of the text that shouldnt be matched*

So what I want exactly is to match from the **:** character till an empty newline(\n\s)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about your text ? can't understand what is the goal... Then, have you tried to write a Regex ? If yes, please show us, if not, please do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
/(?<=:\n).*?(?=^$)/gsm
```

But this requires that the last list is followed by an emtpy line as well.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/0MghoD/1

Comment: Thanks! works great with: preg_match_all("/(?<=:\n).*?(?=^$)/sm", $input_lines, $output_array);